# What is this in Python? (type related)

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

I'm relatively new in Python, and I was doing classes.

I was doing this:

```
>>> x = int()
>>> x
0
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> x = str()
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
>>> x = tuple
>>> type(x)
<type 'type'>
>>> x = ()
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> x = blak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blak' is not defined
```

Why does assigning `tuple` to a newly created variable gave it a type of `type`, as opposed to giving it a tuple type? (I'm okay with it not giving the tuple type, since `x = ()` does it.)
Any other word and it (obviously) gives an error.

What did I stumble across here? I can't find anything in the documentation because the search engines aren't really helpful.

Also, now I see if 
`x = str`
or 
`x = int`

also result in

```
type(x) = int
```

And likewise

Comment: A "NameError" has *nothing* to do with "types". It's simply that there is *no identifier `blak`* in the given scope. `blak = "wheee!"; x = blak` (now that `blak` has been introduced as an identifier/local variable, all "works")

Comment: `tuple is a type`, you need `>>> x = ()`

Comment: `tuple` is the type, `tuple()` is an empty tuple, `()` is a tuple literal. `int` is the type, `int()` is an integer with value 0, `0` is a integer literal. `str` is the type, `str()` is an empty string, `''` is a string literal. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

`x = tuple` is a type. `x = tuple()` would be a tuple...

Comment: Ah thank you!! Very clearly explained!
Obviously! I'm assigning `x` to be a `type`. The docs really should simplify it up. Thank you!
I'd have picked this as the answer now, but I need to wait for 11 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out the reason, but I'll try to fill a few gaps.

**In Python, everything is "first-class".** That means that you can assign for example functions and types to variables and use them as original values:

```
def function(): pass
class Class(object): pass

x = function
x()

y = Class
instance = y()
```

That was the reason why you were able to assign tuple to variable. See [post by Guido van Rossum](http://python-history.blogspot.cz/2009/02/first-class-everything.html) for more information.

Now about types, and that might really be confusing. **`tuple` is instance of `type`** (same relation as `1` is instance of `int`). In other words its type is thing called `type`. `type` is used to create an instance of `type` or to determine its type (instance of `type`):

```
x = 1
# determine type
type(x)

# class statement
class A(object):
    pass

# equivavent to previous class statement
# creates a new class (in other words new "type", and in other words new instance of type)
B = type('B', (object, ), {})
```

That's the reason why tuple's type is `type`. See my [blog post](http://grokked.me/post/67446232700/python-instance-class-and-metaclass) for more information. Or just google/bing for metaclass in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`tuple` is a type, as `str` is a type. `tuple()` or `()` is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

`tuple` is a type(built-in object), `x = tuple` just "alias" `x` for `tuple`, see bellow:

```
>>> t = tuple
>>> m = t()
>>> type(m)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: It is **not** a keyword. You can assign to `tuple`. It is instead a built-in, an object shipped with the Python interpreter. `if`, `else`, `return`, `in`, etc. are keywords.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Admit, I confused built-in objects with keywords, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

tuple is the type constructor for tuple types. Other such type constructors also behave similarly in Python:

```
>>> type(tuple)
>>> type(int)
>>> type(dict)
>>> type(str)
```

All will produce `<type 'type'>`.

You can get an instance if these types by calling the as a function, like so:

```
>>> type(tuple())
>>> type(tuple([1,2,3]))
>>> type(())
```

will all produce `<type 'tuple'>`.

Comment: Ok, I got that a bit.
Than I tried this:



`>>> a = type(tuple)
>>> d = a((1,2,3))
>>> type(d)
<type 'type'>
>>> d
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(d)
<type 'type'>`

Why is `type(d)` returning `type 'type'` but just `d` is returning `type 'tuple'` ?
God I'm feeling stupid.

Comment: Okay, I guess `d` holds a `tuple` object, so `d` gives tuple type on the interactive console, but `type(d)` gives `type 'type'` because d is a type, after assigning it to a. Right?

Comment: @TonyK I never thought so much before, it's interesting. Now I consider a variable has two attributes: type and value. In <type 'tuple'>, *type* represents the type and *tuple* represents the value. Call `type(x)` means return the type attribute of x (the one follows `<`).  When comes to `a = type(tuple)`, tuple is a <type 'tuple'> object, so a's value is type and it's type is type, and so on.

Comment: @WKPlus: you are close, in Python, *objects* have types, not *variables*. This is a significant difference between python and languages like C or C++. In those languages, it's variables that have types, and the memory areas referred by those variables are themselves typeless.

Comment: @TonyK: type(x) returns the type of the object pointed by x. The expression type(tuple) returns the type of the tuple type itself, which is type. In other words, the type of any types/class is `type`. Observe what happens when you do: `class A(object): pass`, then `type(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

A *tuple* is an *immutable* ordered sequence of items.  Items of a tuple are arbitrary objects and may be of different types. A  tuple with  exactly two items `(100, 200)` is  often called a *pair* while a tuple with only one item `(3.14,)` is also know as *singleton*.

You can also call the  built-in type tuple to create a tuple. example: `tuple('wow')` builds a tuple equal to `('w','o','w')`.

`tuple()` without  arguments creates and returns an empty tuple.
and
when `x` is iterable `tuple(x)` returns a tuple whose items are same  as the items of `x`.

This  is the elementary theory of tuples. I hope it helps understanding them.